# Using an Android-hosted DNS server to filter website requests

Tags: android, networking, dns, port, rooted-device

I am developing an application with system privileges on a rooted device. I have managed to
change the DNS settings programmatically for the WIFI connection I am connected to. To check, I run the application, connect the device through USB and run "getprop" command from "adb shell". The application successfully changes the DNS for the session and browsers are blocked from connecting to any website using domains.

I have installed an application called [DNS Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.dnsserver) which will run a DNS Server from my Android device. I have set DNS Server to block requests to specific shady websites and forward every other request to the original DNS server, whose IP address is extracted from the WIFI connection settings.

My application on the other hand will change the device's DNS setting and point towards the device's public IP itself. In this manner every request will pass through DNS Server application, which in turn will filter out blocked websites and forward requests to the original DNS Server.

The problem lies in connection between every browser/app request and DNS Server application. From the logs, DNS Server is listening to connections but is not receiving any requests. Is there any other way to achieve this or perhaps someone can enlighten me if I'm setting something wrong?

From my application, I tried to set the device's DNS server to 127.0.0.1 (loopback), the IP address of the device itself (both public and private) but without any success. Connection cannot be established.

Further info: DNS Server requires a port to listen to, but I cannot set this port globally (I'm assuming the default 53 DNS Port is being used for every request).